# How does one vertically center the heading for a 'part' in ConTeXt?

Tags: sectioning, vertical-alignment, context

My best effort thus far has been to simply add a big blank as a before perameter:

```
\setuphead[part][placehead=yes, alternative=middle,before={\blank[12*big,force]},
    header=empty]
```

Obviously, this might work for a given paper size, but seems inelegant as a solution.

Have I missed an easier method for doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [`makeup`](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/setupmakeup) to set up a custom page layout. Here I used the pre-defined `standard` makeup, which centres vertically.

```
\setuphead
  [part]
  [placehead=yes,
   alternative=middle,
   before=\startstandardmakeup,
   after=\stopstandardmakeup,
   header=empty]

\starttext
  \startpart [title=Part One]
  \stoppart
\stoptext
```

You can also create your own makeup and use the `align` key for the vertical alignment. This approach is more flexible. By default makeups do not increment the page counter (thanks to Aditya for pointing that out). This can be fixed with the `pagestate` key.

```
\definemakeup
  [part]
  [align=middle,
   pagestate=start]

\setuphead
  [part]
  [placehead=yes,
   alternative=middle,
   before=\startpartmakeup,
   after=\stoppartmakeup,
   header=empty]

\starttext
  \startpart [title=Part One]
  \stoppart
\stoptext
```

Comment: Note that, by default, a `makeup` does not increment page number.

Comment: Now that is exactly the kind of elegance I was looking for. I knew about makeups but I hadn't thought to use them in that way. Thanks very much!

Comment: Can we use `vfill` somewhere instead of using startpartmakeup?